# Ethernet is fast but WiFi is very slow?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet, wireless-router

I am experiencing persistent issues with slow WiFi speeds despite having a fast Ethernet connection. Despite upgrading my internet plan to 300 Mbps and using a router with a 2.4GHz frequency, I am only achieving speeds of around 90 Mbps on my Wi-Fi network.

To attempt to address this, I purchased a new TP-Link router with 5GHz support and connected it via LAN port, expecting improved performance, as per the customer care of the ISP. However, the issue persists even after replacing wires, changing ports, and resetting the router multiple times. Despite these troubleshooting efforts, the problem remains unresolved.

I'm using [TP-Link Archer C54](https://www.tp-link.com/in/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-c54/), as I'm testing new WiFi is in my room no other users are connect, currently only my laptop. The speed supported by the new router is 5GHz and 2.4GHz. I mentioned about an old router, I'm connected to that router through LAN cable (where I got 300mbps speed). My location is India.

Speed test with LAN cable:
[image: Speed test with LAN cable.]

Speed test with WiFi:
[image: Speed test with WiFi.]

Comment: What WiFi adapter are you using? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Over what range? % GHz has less penetrating power than 2.4 GHz. What modem in the PC? Is the area electrically noisy? How many devices are sharing WiFi?

Comment: Which TP-Link router ?

Comment: Sounds like either a distance/barrier issue between client and router, or a WiFi config issue if the WiFi client has a 2.4Ghz AC/5Ghz AC or higher network card. For example, WiFi network on the router should be configured with an actual channel number and not set to _Auto_ _(except with 160Mhz bandwidths, which should be Auto)_. For 2.4Ghz, channels: `1`, `6`, or `11` | For 5Ghz: highest or next highest channel _(`157` works well for AC in the US)_. The channel's bandwidth should be set to the highest available - For 2.4Ghz: likely 40Mhz | For 5Ghz AC: likely 80Mhz | For ACM: likely 160Mhz

Comment: @JW0914 I updated the channel to highest available but still the issue persists.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik my area is a village area so no noise issues are there 

Comment: The TP-Link Archer C54 is a cheap corner-cutting ripoff piece of shit because it only has 10/100 Ethernet ports, not gigabit. So the fastest speed you can get from wired to wireless is 94Mbps (Ethernet is 94% efficient), even though the 5GHz wireless could hit over 600Mbps without that restriction. The Archer A6 (also sold as the Archer C6) is the equivalent product but with proper gigabit Ethernet ports so that its Wi-Fi radio can reach its full 600+ Mbps potential.

Comment: 5Ghz and 2.4Ghz are radio signal frequency channels, they are not speeds.

Comment: What is the model or wireless specifications of your laptop or other device(s) you are connecting to this network?